# For which numbers $l \leq |K|$ field $K$ has subfield, which has $l$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, cyclic-groups

char$(K) = p$, $|K|= p^n$, $|K^{\times}| = p^n-1.$

We know that $K^{\times}$ is cyclic group. Let $H$ be a cyclic subgroup of $K^{\times}$. Subgroup of cyclic group is also cyclic, so $H$ is cyclic and $|H|\mid|K^{\times}|$.

Let $|H| = r,\ r\mid p^n-1, \ p^n-1 = r q,\,\, q \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
Each element in $H$ has inverse element (from definition on cyclic group). I just add $0$ and we have subfield. So, $l = r + 1$, where $r \mid p^n-1$.

How to show that $r = p^k - 1$ for $k \leq n$?

Comment: If $H$ is a **subgroup** of $K^\times$ its order must be coprime to $p$, so $r$ cannot equal a power of $p$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown youre right, $r = p^k - 1$, my mistake

Comment: If $L$ is a subfield of $K$, then $K$ is a vector space over $L$, so $|K|$ must be a power of $|L|$.